# Show next hidden element in div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I've got a div with a number of similar elements inside, e.g:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

I want to show only the first `li` when I load the page, and then I want to have a `click` function in place that loads the **next hidden item** so that two `li`s are showing. And continue onwards so that each item can be shown with a click from the same button.

I attempted to hide the first item on load with jQuery, by using `addClass`

I then wanted to, on click, find the `first` that `hasClass` and `addClass` for the new class.

```
$('li').addClass('hide-listings');
$('li').first().removeClass('hide-listings').addClass('show-listings');

$('#load').click(function() {
  $('li').first().hasClass('hide-listings').removeClass('hide-listings').addClass('show-listings');
});
```

However this doesn't work at all. Any ideas on how to do this?

### [Codepen](http://codepen.io/franhaselden/pen/jbexrm)

Comment: just a small tip, you don't need both hide and show. use only hide, and just add\remove it according to the logic...

Comment: @LiranBo can you explain with a code example please?

Comment: please check my answer below

Comment: yes, editing my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your JS with this:

```
$(function() { // when page is done loading

    $('li')
        .addClass('hide-listings'); // add classes to li's

    $('li') // get li
        .first() // only get first
        .removeClass('hide-listings') // remove a class
        .addClass('show-listings'); // add a class

    $('#load')
        .click(function() { // when #load is clicked
          $('ul') // get ul
            .find('.hide-listings') // find class
            .first() // get only the first, if not found, stop here
            .removeClass('hide-listings') // remove class
            .addClass('show-listings'); // add class
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is more easy way

**HTML** (same as before)

```
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<div id="load">Load more...</div>
```

**CSS** (even more easy, 1 line)

```
li {display:none;}
```

**JS**

```
$('li').first().show();

$('#load').click(function() {
  $('li:hidden').first().show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example. very simple - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/odjo2j9b/)

At first, get all the jQuery selected elements for 'li' and apply addclass starting from the element in index `1` - notice that gt(0) means greater than 0.

After that on every click I search for the first li which has the `hide-listings` class and remove it.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<div id="load">Load more...</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('li:gt(0)').addClass('hide-listings');  //hide all the li elements in the jquery selector starting from 1 (gt(0) = greater than 0)


$('#load').click(function() {
  $('li.hide-listings').first().removeClass('hide-listings');  //onclick get the first li that has the hide-listeing class and remove that class.

});
```

**CSS**

```
.hide-listings{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to use classes to show/hide elements. You can do that using the jquery hide() and show() methods.

Your javascript file would look like this:

```
$('li').hide();
$('li').first().show();

var n = 1;
$('#load').click(function() {
  $('li').eq(n).show();
  n++;

});
```

You first hide all the li elements and you show the first one. You have a variable n which keeps track of the current li element and use eq() method to select the element at index n. You then increment n each time 'Show more...' is pressed.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwyjXM)